# gap between responsive buttons css

Tags: html, css

I need to make responsive `50%` categories buttons (or equal width, responsive and centered), always two in the same row.

**PROBLEM**

Looks easy but its tricky, how do I make a 20px white middle gap?

```css
div{
margin: 0 auto;

max-width:400px;
}

.gifsMainCategories{
 list-style:none;
 font-size:0;
 margin:10px auto;
 padding:0;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
}
.gifsMainCategories li{
 display:inline-block;
 width:50%; font-size:16px;
     height:60px;
     line-height:60px;
background:red; 
margin:10px auto;
 
}

.gifsMainCategories li:nth-child(2n+1) {
background: #17bf63;
   } 

.gifsMainCategories li:nth-child(2n+2) {
background: #794bc4;
   }
```

```html
<div>

<ul class="gifsMainCategories">
<li>Dance</li>
<li>shame</li>
<li>love</li>
<li>anger</li>
<li>scare</li>
<li>shocking</li>
<li>claps</li>
<li>sad</li>
<li>well done</li>
<li>Win</li>
<li>really?</li>
<li>I dont know...</li>
<li>Dream</li>
<li>Boring</li>
<li>Slap</li>
<li>Oops...</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result just by changing your width to adjust the space between two buttons using calc() methond for li element. Try this code.

```
.gifsMainCategories li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:40%;
    font-size:16px;
    height:60px;
    line-height:60px;
    background:red; 
    margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: I avoid mentioning not using `calc()` I already had some prroblems using that parameter.

Comment: is ther no other way? plain css

Comment: If you don't need them to be exactly 50%, you can make them something like 40% each and have the margins on left and right. This would make enough space for the gap between them.

Comment: ya, I think this is going to have to be the css settings by now. it works fine. feel free edit your answer to mark it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for that using

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
div{
margin: 0 auto;

max-width:400px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gifsMainCategories{
 list-style:none;
 font-size:0;
 margin:10px auto;
 padding:0;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
}
.gifsMainCategories li{
 width:50%; font-size:16px;
     height:60px;
     line-height:60px;
margin:10px auto;
padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;
float:left;
 
}

.gifsMainCategories li:nth-child(2n){
padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
 
}

.gifsMainCategories li div{
 font-size:16px;
  width:100%;
     height:60px;
     line-height:60px;
background:red; 
 
}
```

```html
<div>

<ul class="gifsMainCategories">
<li><div>Dance</div></li>
<li><div>shame</div></li>
<li><div>Dance</div></li>
<li><div>shame</div></li>
<li><div>Dance</div></li>
<li><div>shame</div></li>
<li><div>Dance</div></li>
<li><div>shame</div></li>
<li><div>Dance</div></li>
<li><div>shame</div></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I used `.gifsMainCategories li:nth-child(2n){background-color` in my example because In case this paramenter doesnt work the estructure of the  content wouldnt move or ater its position....but In this case, is it reliable to use cross browser? any other option besides using this?

Comment: you can give class to 2th,4th.. li instead of .gifsMainCategories li:nth-child(2n) it.

Answer (score 0):

Since OP wants to avoid `calc` the `width`a solution using `flex` and the `border` property to simulate the margins could be:

```
.gifsMainCategories{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
.gifsMainCategories li{
  box-sizing: inherit;
  font-size:16px;
  height:60px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 5px solid white;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

Also added `box-sizing: border-box;` I don't know if it is set for everything in your original `css`